# How to make an LED animation in IPhoneSDK?

Tags: iphone, animation

I need to create an animation where an LED blinks once. Not the LED flashlight on the Iphone 4 !! Just a simple on screen animation.

Now, here is how I would do this. I would have 2 images, 1x LED off and 1x LED on. Both images would be at the same spot and the LED on would be 100% transparent. Then I would start an animation that would set the transparency to 0% and back to 100%.

Does that sound as a good way to do this ?

**(Update from deleted answer)**

Ok here is the part where I do the animate part

```
[remoteControlLED setHighlighted:YES];
[remoteControlLED setAnimationDuration:15.0];   
[remoteControlLED startAnimating];
```

As you can see, I use the highlight to switch it on, but how do I turn it off again. I mean I need a delay before doing it. Is there a way to have a call when the animation is ready or do I need my own timer ?

Comment: Do you want to animate or just switch between on and off? If you just want to switch you could have one UIImageView and just change it's image property.

Comment: Well, I am not sure how the animation would look like, so switching might be the easy option, but I would like to try the animation first ?

Comment: If you want to animate then approach you've suggested above is probably the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no callback for UIImageView Animation, but if you just need the animation to repeat a certain amount of times, you can use the setAnimationRepeatCount

Comment: I use this now  ' [self performSelector:@selector(ledOFF) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];'